# in Visual Studio: why does the QuickWatch window add "Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView" to List<T> element expressions?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

for example:

```cs
var p = new {
    rg = new List<string> {
        "one",
        "two",
    }
};
```

QuickWatch `p`, and click on `p.rg[0]` in the tree.

the expression becomes: `new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView<string>(p.rg).Items[0]`

what is this nonsense, and how do i get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

The "Expression" text box shows the full name of whatever node you have selected in the tree.  The full name is the expression you would need to evaluate if you want to see only the value you have selected.
`List<T>` isn't an array and doesn't actually have a member named "[0]".  If you take a look at "Raw View", you'll see the actual implementation members of `List<T>`.  Most people don't care about the implementation and only want to see the items in the list.  Because of this, `List<T>` has a [DebuggerTypeProxy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8eyd8zc.aspx).  Type proxies allow customizing the view of an object in the debugger.  For `List<T>`, the type proxy is `Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView`.  In order to evaluate element 0 directly, you need to instantiate the type proxy, then get the value of element 0 (`TypeProxy.Items[0]`).

Comment: yeah, but List<T> implements "this[int]", so "p.rg[0]" is a valid expression for that element. i understand "Most people don't care about the implementation", but who do you think cares about internal debugger implementations such as "DebuggerTypeProxy"?. if you're going to the lengths to hide the internal members in the tree, can't you go the extra but and hide the proxies in the expression combo?

Comment: @Spongman, You are correct that the debugger could use "this[]" in theory.  Problem is "this[]" is C# syntactic sugar.  It actually maps to a compiler generated indexer that is a member of List<T>.  The debugger is architected to be agnostic of language so using "this[]" would be a bit of a hack.  In terms of hiding the nasty expression, I agree that it's ugly to see some these generated expressions. However, as a developer I like having the option to take the expression and make modifications to it before evaluating it again.

Comment: in which use-case is it useful to see the DebuggerTypeProxies? the only one i can think of is if you're developing those proxies or the debugger itself. for the other 99.99% of times it noise. i understand that the existing design makes it hard to hide them, but i don't think that's really a justification.